# Javascript write over PDF with no libraries

Tags: javascript, pdf

I have a web page with 100 links data, and daily, I have to go over those links, and to fill in hand written forms based on some assumptions I can make from the data.

To automate this, all I gotta do is somehow load a PDF onto a canvas (this part is not very important, I can reproduce the PDF in canvas myself, but it would be nicer to load it), write on the canvas, and export it as PDF.
I can also do it in HTML, and export HTML as PDF.

Constraints:

- This is a closed network, so I cannot use any library, and/or copy code from the internet. Whatever I do must be typed by me, so the solution must be somewhat possible to type.
- I have no node environment. This has to happen in the browser, and create a download link for like a base64 pdf file.

Comment: I suggest you use a different approach. If you have access to Adobe Acrobat, you can write a JavaScript that will read data from a file then populate form fields and save a new file. Look at the doc.importTextData() method. It imports a row of data from a text file. The entries in the first row of the text file are the column names of the tab delimited data. These names are also field names for text fields present in the PDF file. When a row of data is imported, each column datum becomes the field value of the field that corresponds to the column to which the data belongs.

Comment: @joelgeraci I only have Adobe reader installed there, so can't use acrobat

Comment: I cannot see how this will be possible without the use of external libraries. The PDF internals are complex and generally not human readable. With something like PDF.js, it would be trivial.